# Props passed to dynamic component in Vue are not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am using Vue's dynamic component to load a component depending on what is to be displayed. As these components all have different props I build an object and pass it in via v-bind depending on what I need to use from the original state model.

However, when I do this I lose the reactive nature of Vue's props data flow. The code sample below shows an example of this with the name changing on the standard component but not on the dynamic version.

I expect this is something to do with the string value being copied into the new object, rather than a reference to the original reactive property. Can anyone advise on how I can make this work as expected?

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component("example-component", {
    props: ["name"],
    template: '<span style="color: green;">{{name}}</span>'
    }
);

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        person: {
            name: "William"
        },
        component: null
    }
});

// Load the dynamic component
setTimeout(function() {

    app.component = {
        is: 'example-component',
        props: { name: app.person.name }
    }

    // Change the name
    setTimeout(function() {
        app.person.name = "Sarah";
    }, 2000);

}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
            
    <strong>Standard Component</strong><br />
    <example-component :name="person.name"></example-component><br /><br />

    <div v-if="component">
        <strong>Dynamic Component</strong><br />
        <component :is="component.is" v-bind="component.props"></component>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The template should reference the data or computed in the Vue to have it reactive. Otherwise it's just an ordinary variable, it wouldn't get the [reactivity](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two different objects here, `person` and `component`, which are declared in the `app` component's `data` property.

It is `app.component.props.name` which is bound to the component's prop, but you are modifying `app.person.name` which is separate and not bound to the component.

`app.component.props` and `app.person` *are two separate object instances*, and so modifying one of these object's properties will have no effect on the other.

It's difficult to suggest a suitable solution to your problem because your example is too simple (and a little contrived). What you want will not work so long as you are copying the `name` value between different objects.

I'd redo all of the code, and perhaps use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) instead. But with the least amount of changes you can do this:

```es6
app.component = {
  is: 'example-component',
  props: {
    get name() { return app.person.name; }
  }
}
```

Now `app.component.props.name` is actually a getter function which returns `app.person.name`. Vue can observe this, and will react when `app.person.name` changes.

Comment: I know the objects are different, I was hoping the concept of composition could be applied. I want state changes to be honoured inside the new component, not just have the value copied into it. If I change "props: app.person.name" to "props: app.person" it works. But I can't use this as a solution going forward as new objects with new properties need to be composed. This is the part I can't work out.

Comment: It sounded like from your question that you didn't understand why changing the value didn't cause the prop to be updated too, hence my explanation. I've updated my answer with a bit more info.

Comment: Awesome, your updated code worked perfect. I've searched for ages on this and couldn't find an answer. Thank you for taking the time to give that detailed response!