# Vue dynamic component props are not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have props I'm trying to pass to a dynamic component.  My other components update when the prop is updated, just not my dynamic component..

```
<v-component
  :is="activeComponent"
  v-bind="props"
/>
```

I have the props computed like some mentioned in SO

```
computed: {
  props() {
    return {
      commissionsRunning: this.isUpdating,
    };
  },
},
```

However when `this.isUpdating` changes my dynamic component is not rerendered.

Here's a few resources I checked out

- [Props passed to dynamic component in Vue are not reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744339/props-passed-to-dynamic-component-in-vue-are-not-reactive)
- [Why isn't the prop reactive in the dynamic component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883790/why-isnt-the-prop-reactive-in-the-dynamic-component)
- [Intertiajs + Vue prop not reactive in dynamic component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68994294/intertiajs-vue-prop-not-reactive-in-dynamic-component)
- [Vue Dynamic Component & Dynamic props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713271/vue-dynamic-component-dynamic-props)
- https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/vue2/dynamic-component

I've also tried other syntaxes

```
<v-component
  :is="activeComponent"
  v-bind="{commissionsRunning: this.isUpdating}"
/>
```

```
<v-component
  :is="activeComponent"
  v-bind:commissionsRunning="isUpdating"
/>
```

```
<v-component
  :is="activeComponent"
  :commissionsRunning="isUpdating"
/>
```

Comment: ok think I got it working, tomorrow I'll brush up the solution and see what fixed it